# Is it possible to have different loaders for path with and without query params or conditionally skip a loder when adding them in React Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a loader for path `/items` which fetches a lot of data from API, so I use a deferred loader. I want to conditionally render the `<Supense><Await>` code only when there are no search query params (meaning initial fetch from the server), but then to use the already fetched items and filter them based on the search query parameters.

1. `/items` -> fetch from API for 3 seconds
2. submit a form (e.g. search input) which navigates with query params (e.g. `search=test`)
3. `/items?search=test` -> filters the already fetched items based on the query params with `useSearchParams`

- **Issue**: it re-renders the component, goes through the `<Suspense><Await>` again

What is the best approach with such case? I tried using useState, Location State (from `<Form state>`), but it is difficult to go around not rendering the `<Await>` in order to use the already fetched data.

Am I missing a valuable pattern that can be used in such scenario? It seems too common to not have an already established pattern

Update - a quick code example using Form state and Location for initially displaying items fetched from API vs locally saved items filtered based on a query param (`search`):

Loader function: `const loader= (() => defer({ itemsAsync: getItems() })) satisfies LoaderFunction; // getItems() is Promise`

Component:

```
const { itemsAsync } = useLoaderData();
const { state: { savedItems } } = useLocation();

const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const searchQueryParam = searchParams.get('search')?.toLowerCase() ?? '';

const filterItems = (items: Item[]) => items.filter((item) => item.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchQueryParam));


return state ? (
  <div>
    <Form state={{savedItems: items}}>
      <input type="text" name="search" />
      <input type="submit" hidden />
    </Form>
    {filterItems(state?.items).map((item) => <div>{item}</div>)}
  </div>
) : (
  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading items...</div>}>
    <Await resolve={itemsAsync}>
      {(items) => (
        <div>
          <Form state={{savedItems: items}}>
            <input type="text" name="search" />
            <input type="submit" hidden />
          </Form>
          {items.map((item) => <div>{item}</div>)}
        </div>
      )}
    </Await>
  </Suspense>
);
```

On submitting the Form it simply adds `search` as a query param `/items?search=test` then based on the test we should filter the list and display a subset of the fetched items. This is not working for many reasons - for example the `search` query param is only added in the URL at the very end of the loading process, in this case it fetches new items from the API (e.g. 5 seconds delay) and only then it updates the actual URL. I know that I can also get the params from the loader's `request`, but then I will need to return non-deferred data based on if there are params or not? There must be a simpler way to deal with "caching" data while using query params and I am reinventing the wheel right now.

As I already mentioned the ideal flow in my head would be:

1. `/items` -> fetch from API (slow request ~3 seconds)
2. submit a form (e.g. search input) which navigates with query params (e.g. `search=test`)
3. `/items?search=test` -> filters the already fetched items based on the query params instead of fetching the same items again and then filtering

Comment: It is not exactly clear what problem you are trying to solve for here. If the data has already been fetched, then there should be nothing to Suspense/Await for, the UI has the data. Can you [edit] to clarify the issue/problem and include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: Done. Let me know if it's clear enough and if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel while there are already better established ways to deal with such soft "caching" between route updates

Comment: The issue here may be that when the route's search params are updated that the loader runs again, but doesn't realize it just needs to filter previously fetched data. In other words, the data is fetched again *and then* filtered and returned to the UI. You may need to cache fetched data from initial requests, to be filtered later. Can you [edit] to include your loader logic?

Comment: I already included it. It's just a defer with promise in it. As Rastislav already suggested in their answer this would probably be the only way to deal with this. I was hoping for a much cleaner solution that wouldn't require such overcomplicated conditional rendering in the element component for this path. If only we had the `state` available through `request.state` (or form POST `body` for example) in the loader... :) It would have been so easy to conditionally return promise from server vs "mock" promise with the already existing state/body instead. Or a way to skip loader for query params

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the issue here is that the loaders are only passed the route path params and the request object, so you'd need to read the search params from the `window.location` or from the request object. Their suggestion/solution is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong here but I don't think we can differentiate between routes which differ only by search params on router level.

Hence I'd try to solve it in loader directly and make expensive fetch conditional. Loader function parameter has two properties *params* and *request*. You can convert request.url to an URL object and check if searchParams is non-empty. If it is, you can bail out or use some buffered value.

```
function loader({ request }) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  if (url.searchParams.size > 0) return;
  // your data fetching 
}
```